# How to restore/reset npm configuration to default values?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have played with `npm set` and `npm config set` for several times, now I want to reset to default values (a kind of factory reset).

Does `npm` provide a command to do that? Or should I delete all configuration files by hands then reinstall it?

I need to do it both on Linux CentOS and on Windows 8.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

#### To reset user defaults

Run this in the command line (or [git bash](http://git-scm.com/downloads) on windows):

```
echo "" > $(npm config get userconfig)
npm config edit
```

#### To reset global defaults

```
echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)
npm config --global edit
```

#### If you need sudo then run this instead:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)'
```

Comment: If you need more information on how npm resolves configuration then look over here: https://npmjs.org/doc/config.html

Comment: worked great thanks. i destroyed my settings by installing sinopa :(

Comment: Think current link to npm config documentation is https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config

Comment: What does `npm config edit` accomplish here? Doesn't that just open Vim?

Answer (score 76):

For what it's worth, you can reset to default the value of a config entry with `npm config delete <key>` (or `npm config rm <key>`, but the usage of `npm config rm` is not mentioned in `npm help config`).

Example:

```sh
# set registry value
npm config set registry "https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry"
# revert change back to default
npm config delete registry
```

Comment: this was a big help

Comment: This wrecked my application. Now I get an error: Cannot find module 'config-chain'

Comment: Removing the node_modules folder fixed the config chain error.

Comment: Clearly what I was looking for after npm tries to pull from a private registry by default! Big thanks

Comment: I was dwelling in my tears for a couple of hours now, thank you!
I changed the default path of npm because of a permission error and everything stopped working.

Answer (score 41):

If you run `npm config edit`, you'll get an editor showing the current configuration, and also a list of options and their default values.

But I don't think there's a 'reset' command.

Comment: I have removed only the adress, saved and closed the file. Then I have reopend the file, and the complete line registry= was deleted

Answer (score 15):

If it's about just one property - let's say you want to temporarily change some default, for instance disable CA checking: you can do it with

`npm config set ca ""`

To come back to the defaults for that setting, simply

`npm config delete ca`

To verify, use `npm config get ca`.

Comment: In my case: npm config -g rm <key>   "-g is for global"

Answer (score 6):

**npm config edit**

Opens the config file in an editor. Use the --global flag to edit the global config.
now you can delete what ever the registry's you don't want and save file.

**npm config list** will display the list of available now.

Answer (score 6):

Config is written to `.npmrc` files so just delete it. NPM looks up config in this order, setting in the next overwrites the previous one. So make sure there might be global config that usually is overwritten in per-project that becomes active after you have deleted the per-project config file. `npm config list` will allways list the active config.

1. npm builtin config file (`/path/to/npm/npmrc`)
2. global config file (`$PREFIX/etc/npmrc`)
3. per-user config file (`$HOME/.npmrc`)
4. per-project config file (`/path/to/my/project/.npmrc`)