# Forever: command not found

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, forever

I am getting a

**forever: command not found** error when I run a nodejs process using the forever command as a cronjob (in an amazon ec2 machine):
the bash script I am using has the following code:

cd to/location/of/the/nodejs/file

forever start file.js

but I am able to run this file by using bash script.sh but I get the forever:command not found error when I run it via cronjob

I am confused dont know what could be the reason for this.

Has anybody else faced this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific.

Comment: what language are you using, explain your problem in detail

Comment: I am using javascript

Comment: If you do not verify using the server, anyone can hack this. Client side validations are non validations, you must validate using the server.

Comment: do it i will hack into in your site :)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Run this command: `npm install forever -g`

`-g` is to install it globally.

Comment: What does -g do? And how could it run from bash before?

Comment: -g is for install it globally.

Comment: This fixed my issue for sure. Though it's not as clean to do this globally. I wonder if there is a better solution.

Comment: Remember to restart the console after installing it, and if you installed this module locally, easiest is to uninstall it first (else the command will refer to the local version)

Answer (score 11):

For other users who face this problem:

you have to add the path of forever module and then run the script as a cronjob.

In linux the path normally is:

**/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever start file.js**

just use this command in your script and the error **forever:command not found** will not bother you.

I know there must be some other fancy ways to do this but I am happy with this hack

Comment: Running `sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever /usr/bin/forever` would create a simlink to allow you to run `sudo forever ...`

Answer (score 10):

in case azero0's solution doesn't work for you and you're running linux, try

```
sudo npm install forever -g
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have already tried:

```
sudo npm install forever -g
```

and still get `forever:command not found` pay attention to the first line in the output.  This should be something like:

```
/<node_bin_path>/forever -> /lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever
```

where `node_bin_path` is the place in which the executable is located.  This is most likely not where you expect.

This may be because `node` in your path is a symbolic link.  In this case `forever` will be installed in the actual install location of `node` not the location of the symbolic link.

Comment: I think I have a problem related to this. So what is the solution? One day I ran `sudo npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'` and I think this is causing the problem.

Comment: Found the solution! Reset the configurations with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20934521/1889607

Answer (score 1):

it seems forever not found in globally, use the below command to solve

```
npm i forever -g
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo npm install forever --global
```

this worked for me on ubuntu 16.04 server and nodejs v7.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Below bash script Code Check your script running. If not running Stop and Start and notification mail.

Crontab

```
*/1     *       *       *       *       sh /root/yourscriptdirectory/checklive.sh >> /root/yourscriptdirectory/cron.log 2>&1
```

checklive.sh

chmod +x ./checklive.sh

```
cd /root/yourscriptdirectory/

ps xa | grep -F "/usr/local/bin/node /root/yourscriptdirectory/script.js"  | grep -Fv "grep"  > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo ""
else
  echo "script.js not running. Restart"
  /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever stop script.js
  /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever start script.js
  echo "STOP : script.js Process is stoped restarting..."  | mail -s "STOP : script.js Process is stoped restarting..." "<yourmail@gmail.com>" &
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably switched to `yarn` recently and installed `forever` with `yarn`, as well. Instead, fallback to `npm` (just for `forever`):

`sudo npm install forever -g`

( `g` == global )