# NPM Not functioning correctly

Tags: node.js, npm

My NPM has been acting up recently. I have been having issues installing packages globally. For example when I type npm install -g ionic, ionic will work where I ran that, but nowhere else on my computer. Also when I type npm install, it will install all sorts of files directly to the folder instead of to the node_modules folder.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934343/how-to-restore-reset-npm-configuration-to-default-values

Comment: Perfect Thank you! @Aᴍɪʀ

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: [How to restore/reset npm configuration to default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934343/how-to-restore-reset-npm-configuration-to-default-values)

#### To reset user defaults

Run this in the command line (or [git bash](http://git-scm.com/downloads) on windows):

```
echo "" > $(npm config get userconfig)
npm config edit
```

#### To reset global defualts

```
echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)
npm config --global edit
```

#### If you need sudo that run this instead:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig)'
```