# Can' Install Typings in NPM

Tags: npm

I'm having trouble installing typings in my typescript project.  If I try to install Jasmine, this is what I get:

```
>npm install --save-dev @types/jasmine
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/jasmine@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     2018-01-08T15_37_28_150Z-debug.log
```

Here's another example with Mocha:

```
>npm install --save-dev @types/mocha
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/mocha@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     2018-01-08T15_38_52_028Z-debug.log
```

Can someone help me out?  I'm using npm version 5.1.0.  I'm using tsc version 2.4.1

Comment: Have you tried to read `2018-01-08T15_37_28_150Z-debug.log`and `2018-01-08T15_38_52_028Z-debug.log`?

Comment: Looks my my package source is wrong.  It's set to some internal company source.  Do you know how to set it back to whatever the default NPM source is??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore/reset npm configuration to default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934343/how-to-restore-reset-npm-configuration-to-default-values)