# Why does NPM create unwanted folder when installing packages?

Tags: npm

Every time when I install any npm package, it creates a folder called 'tmpnodejsnpm-cache'. See the picture below.

Why does this happen?

[The unwanted generated folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/affKY.png)

Comment: I'd guess because your NPM cache configuration is wrong, that looks like an approximation of `tmp\nodejs\npm-cache`.

Comment: Thank for reply. Do you know how to reset the configuration to default?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20934343/3001761