# npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE Error when npm install

Tags: npm, react-scripts

I cloned my project into ubuntu server for deployment, but when i try to install dependencies and I encountered Maximum Call stack size exceeded error. Then following answers on stackoverflow I deleted node modules and package.json. But now when I do npm install I encounter the below error.

```
npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
npm ERR! errno ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@material-ui%2fcore failed, reason: The "msecs" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('600001')

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ute/.npm/_logs/2021-07-20T08_00_38_282Z-debug.log
```

also getting the same type of error when  I do npm update -g

```
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/npm failed,
reason: The "msecs" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('600001')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you do not realize set your npm config previously, because I also am like that, and now I already found the solution:

you can try this

```bash
echo "" > $(npm config get userconfig) 
npm config edit
```

or

```bash
echo "" > $(npm config get globalconfig) 
npm config --global edit
```

and if you still feel it doesn't work you can try this link below:

[How to restore/reset npm configuration to default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934343/how-to-restore-reset-npm-configuration-to-default-values)

Answer (score 0):

You should not remove package.json file because of this file contain the necessary details of dependencies as modules and other data.

You can use `npm init` in your specific directory to create a package.json file and then install your modules with this command `npm i -S [your_dependency]`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was the .npmrc file stored in "C:\users\username\". Just deleting it everything worked again.